# Instead of actual image from URL some random image is displaying in image view : iOS,Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have implemented a feature to change profile picture. Implementation flow is following

> Select image -> upload to server -> Download from server and display
>   it user.

This flow works fine randomly. Image uploading always succeeds and i always get a URL in response. But when i try to display that image, somehow it does not get display in image view. But the same URL displays image in all browsers (Sfari,chrome,IE). I am unable to understand what is the issue i am doing in uploading or downloading of image.

Code is attached below. Any help would be appreciated.

> Image uploading:-

```
func updateProfile(userUpdateRequest:UsersRequest ,completionBlock completion: @escaping ( _ fileURL : String)->Void, failureBlock failure: @escaping ( _ error: String) -> Void)  {

        let url = "\(SPConfigurations.getBaseURL())/\(APIConstants.getProfileUpdateRequestRoute(userRequest: userUpdateRequest))"

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            if (userUpdateRequest.image != nil) {
                let  fileData = userUpdateRequest.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
                 multipartFormData.append(fileData, withName: "file", fileName:UUID().uuidString , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }
        }, to: url, method: .post, headers:APIConstants.authHeaders()) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in

                    if let err = response.error {
                        failure(err.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    } else {
                        if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                            if let dataValue = result["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                                if let fileUrl = dataValue["profile_picture_url"] as? String {
                                    completion(fileUrl)
                                } else {
                                    completion("")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                failure(encodingError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

> Image Downloading:- Its extension of Imageview & its working fine for
>   all images except the ones i am uploading.

```
func setImage (urlString: String,placeHolderString : String = "placeholder") {

        let placeHolderImage = UIImage.init(named: placeHolderString)

        if(urlString.trim() == "") {
            self.image = placeHolderImage
            return
        }

        self.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: urlString)!, placeholder: placeHolderImage, options: nil, progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) -> () in

        }, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if(image != nil) {
                    self.image = image
                }
            }
        }
        )
    }
```

> Example URL which does not get displayed :
>   https://snikpic-image-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/5013571a-f020-4321-a59f-522da6269635/d7872db2-5b9f-4d4c-8839-7604bffc02d7.jpeg

Comment: Its hard to track what you url you are getting and what you are loading with the code. On alternate, you can `import AlomfireImage` in your class and can use `imageview.setImage(url: )` method to check this.

Comment: I have attached a test URL above.. which is not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

try to set the image without progress block

```
self.imageView?.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: urlString)!)
```